# Can I track the MAC address of my stolen laptop by service tag number?

Tags: mac-address, anti-theft

My Dell Vostro laptop was stolen five days back. Many valuable documents were on it, so how can I trace the MAC address of my stolen laptop?

Can the MAC address be traced through the service tag number?

Comment: Call Dell and ask them if they know the MAC Address of your computer's NETWORK INTERFACE(that's what it actually is).  I doubt it. But it's possible. It's possible in theory. Because the service tag is unique to your computer, and they may know about the network controller's MAC. If Dell are that organized. Ask them and report back. (though as MAC Addresses are also unique, it's possible Dell don't bother as it's a lot to record). I doubt knowing the MAC Address will be useful to you though, because the router it is connected to will strip it off anyway before it hits the Internet.

Comment: So I guess the MAC Address might be of use if you knew what router it's connected to, or if you knew it was one of a bunch of computers that were recovered. But otherwise I don't see the use. It's probably not a good idea to store valuable data on a laptop and if you do then you should perhaps synchronize it every day. or find some kind of solution. At home you can use windows file sharing and save documents on a "network drive", like, the hard drive of another computer that doesn't leave your house.

Comment: Thanks barlop for the answer.well i used my LG mobile internet to access internet in my stolen laptop so is there any chance to retrive the mac id of the laptop from the phone. Thanks once again

Comment: If you connected to or accessed it in any way directly,with no switch/router in between, then you'd be able to see its MAC while communicating with it. But afterwards, you'd only be able to if a log was made, and the only thing I could have thought of that'd log it is the firewall log which if you look at a line of it,you see it doesn't include MAC address.u should use software/ a service like dropbox to backup your files such as documents.Even 2GB space offered free might be enough.That or somehow syncing files on your laptop to a working directory at a comp at home when u connect it at home

Comment: Dell might be your best chance of knowing your MAC address. But unless you know what network/router a laptop is on, then trying to find it from its MAC address, seems like a fool's errand.  And if you knew which network/router a laptop is on, then you could probably walk in and see the thief using it anyway without the MAC address.